# mouse events on overlapping SVG elements

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, dom-events

How to handle click events on overlapping svg elements? I am using Reaphael.js library.

Problem is that top `<svg>` DOM element is intercepting mouse event, even if bottom element is not overlapped by any drawing. My question is how to make both circles in my example clickable and still keep them in two svg elemnts?

Here is my code:

**CSS:**

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}

#container>svg {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var topLayer = Raphael('container', 200, 200);

var bottomLayer = Raphael('container', 200, 200);

topLayer.circle(100, 100, 50)
  .attr({
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: false
  })
  .mousedown(function(){alert('Top layer')});

bottomLayer.circle(120, 120, 50)
  .attr({
    fill: 'pink',
    stroke: false
  })
  .mousedown(function(){alert('Bottom layer')});
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pangorgo/cqf7k/) example

**PS:** I know that I can achieve layering in single `<svg>` DOM elemnt, but this is not a case. My bottom SVG element have zoom and pan capabilities, while top SVG element should be static.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: one layer is above the other, i don't think you can click on the layer below

Comment: A workaround can be that you apply mousedown event on your container div and then calculate if the coordinates of the event are within the range of your svg elements. Then do the changes that you want to using javascript.

Answer (score 10):

You can manipulate css property called pointer-events by setting it to none. This will result in allowing all events flowing through the layer that is marked with pointer-events:none.

You can see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/krul/6SmQ9/2/) fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/krul/6SmQ9/2/

```
#container {
    pointer-events:none;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px
}
#container>svg {
    pointer-events:none;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
svg circle {
    pointer-events:visible;    
}
```