# Raphael js elements in different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, raphael

I am developing a website where diagrams can be dragged around the screen, using raphael js.

An well-known limitation of Raphael js is that it there is no built in method for grouping and dragging elements around.

In order to deal with this, I was thinking of creating an individual div element for each diagram. Each div would then have its own raphael **canvas** and I would use jquery ui to drag these mini raphael canvases around.

I tried this with a a few elements and it works perfectly, but before I implement this into a fully functional prototype I was wondering if anyone has used similar solutions and if there are any known issues with this approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works for you it is great, still there is one limitation I am aware of. When you want to handle mouse click events of the elements on different svg canvases, there might be a problem when these canvases overlap. When clicking on the element which is overlapped by the other canvas, even if the canvas does not contain any elements, you will not be able to intercept the click. This issue is broadly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822756/mouse-events-on-overlapping-svg-elements).